# Loop free sum of column wise operations producing a matrix with Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen

Is there a loop free way to do this with Eigen?

```
Matrix3Xf a, b;
Matrix3f m;
m.setZero();
for (size_t i = 0; i < a.cols(); ++i) {
    m += a.col(i) * b.col(i).transpose();
}
```

Comment: `m = a*b.transpose();` (assuming `b.cols()==a.cols()`)

Comment: I have much to learn. I will accept that as an answer if you post it.